# Converting jquery string to php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

So I have a php which gets set of coordinates from the database , I want it to run through a jquery variable. 
  This is the PHP -

```
$sql = "SQL that works";
$vari = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loc))
{echo "[";
 echo "''";
 echo $row['cor1'];
 echo ",";
 echo $row['cor2'];
 echo "]";
}
```

This is the jquery that I want it to pass through in this form -

```
var markers = [
['', 51.503454,-0.119562],
['', 51.499633,-0.124755]
];
```

Comment: why dont you use ajax call to prepare data?

Comment: Would it not be easier to `json_encode()` what you get back to work with the result set in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have to change your php code like below:-

```
$sql = "SQL that works";
$vari = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$data = array(); //create an rray variable
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loc)){ // use assoc for lighter $row array 
 $data[] = array('',$row['cor1'],$row['cor2']); // create sub-array and assign to final array
}

echo json_encode($data); //return final data to ajax
```

Note:-Now decode this json in your jQuery via `parseJSON()` and do further code.

Comment: what if array value is too large? it can be worst.

Comment: @VK321 it depends what OP actually want to do with the data. he can use load more concept by using some limits to query

Comment: agree - though it's a better solution than what he is trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ajax, you can do something like this.

For the PHP,

```
...
$vari   = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$coOrds = mysqli_fetch_array($loc);
$coOrds = json_encode($coOrds);
?>
```

For the JS,

```
var coOrdsJson = <?php echo $coOrds; ?>;
var coOrds     = $.parseJSON(coOrdsJson);
var markersArr = [];

for (var i=0; i < coOrds.length; i++ ) {
    markersArr[] = "['', " + coOrds[i].cor1 + ", " + coOrds[i].cor2 + "]";
}

var markers = markersArr.join(',');
markers = "[" + markers + "]";
```

Comment: Needless to say - you wouldn't be able to put this JS into a separate JS file, unless you moved the PHP echo variable assign into global scope between <script> tags inside a .php file, before the JS file was included.